# Drupal Commerce: line_item field in user profile?

Tags: 7, commerce

Im trying to achieve the *add to favorites* function, but I cant reference the commerce_product/product_display becose the items that are sold in my situation get customized by the user (add text, images, whatever).

I have a custom line item type called *custom*, where I added the field to handle the customization my users can do.

For the *add to favorites* functionality, i thought to add a line_item field in the user profile, put in it the custom line items created, and when he want to buy it all I have to do is create a new line item copying the fields value and then add it to the cart.

But i have some trouble: when i try to add (for test) the line items in the user's profile page throught the standard widget, I dont get any error message but the line items doesnt get saved..

Are them bounded to commerce_orders only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I ended creating a new **content type (node)**, added all the fields I need/use in the line_item (product_id, display_product_id, my fields where I store customer's customizations, etc..)

When the customer want to buy the item, I simply create the line_item *on the fly* copying all the fields value from the node.

This allow me to handle more easly the display of those *favorites items*, becose they are just nodes: the only thing I did is to use hook_node_access to make those nodes visible only to administrator and to the customer who created them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would not use a line item reference field outside of the order entity type. You might try using an [entity reference field](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) instead with the [inline entity form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module for line item creation / editing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I ended creating a custom node type, on wich I put all the fields in common with the line item: when the user want to buy it, I simply copy all the fields into a new line item and put it in the cart. I'll put my answer ;)